# internal/external font family in ckeditor

Tags: php, jquery, html, ckeditor

i need to get the internal/external font family of content into ckeditor toolbar instead on inline.

```
#editor p span {
  font-family: trebuchet ms,helvetica,sans-serif; 
}
```

and my HTML code is

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true" style="position: absolute; top: 150px; left: 40%;">
  <p style="text-align: justify;"> <span style='font-size: 36px;'>Waqas Ahmed memon</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get the internal/external font family of content into ckeditor toolbar instead on inline"? Would you like to style content inside CKEditor or get styles of some element which are used inside?

Comment: i am using google fonts into ckeditor, as shown in the code above, but CKEditor in not showing the font in toolbar font drop down. As CKEditor accepts the font from inline span and i want to do it externally

Comment: I see what your intentions are. However, Font Family dropdown is based on span elements with inline styling so it does not detect and does not work with external styling.
If you would like to add your custom font to a dropdown you can use `font_names` config (http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-font_names), but still it will work only with spans.

Comment: i have used `font_names`, and i got your point. do we have any alternate to do it with external styling.  Means i have an external css for span Element that is not working for toolbar, How can i pass that style to toolbar.

Comment: Unfortunately, Font Family dropdown works only with span elements with inline styling so without custom development it is not possible to make it work with external stylesheet.

Comment: Are you sure there is no any alternate to do this?

Comment: With the current Font Family dropdown implementation unfortunately not. However, you may write some custom code to integrate `computedStyles` with Font Family dropdown or created some kind of the converted which will add proper span elements. All solutions will need adding some custom code.

Comment: ok thanks Igor Drozdov!

Comment: Hey, Ws Memon, what can we do to get the external styling in font family dropdown?

Comment: its done, i'm using google fonts into ckeditor font's dropdown.